# Docker for Windows application not accessible over browser when connected via VPN

Tags: asp.net, docker, vpn, docker-for-windows

I have docker for windows running windows container. Machine is connected to corporate network via Cisco AnyConnect VPN. We have been having this issue for sometime with no solutions. To explain the problem here is an example. Go to docker image here https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-samples and run the below commands in command prompt / powershell in sequence

`docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/samples:aspnetapp`

`docker run -it --rm -p 8000:80 --name aspnetcore_sample mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/samples:aspnetapp`

replace port `8000` with something else if there is an error in lines of hns file being used. Go to browser and do `http://localhost:8000` assuming its running on port 8000. It doesn't connect for me. Instead of localhost i also tried below command to find the ipaddress of the container running the image and then replace localhost with that ip address but with same response ***unable to connect.***

`docker inspect -f '{{range.NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' container_name_or_id`

here is an screenshot of the network adapter docker sets up by default
[image: network adapter 1 setting]

here is another screenshot of the nat network adapter
[image: nat network adapter]